Sheets swap on Tableau Dashboard using parameter
Can anyone help the issue I have with Tableau?
I tried to swap sheets on Tableau dashboard by using parameter, but once I tried to change the sheets, it still won't work.
what I did was creating sheets (2 sheets) that I want to put on my dahsboard, add a parameter on both sheets (also not forget to add a calculated parameter as well), then on dashboard I was using vertical container and put the sheets I've created before in it, remove/hide the title from both sheets, and also not forget to show the filter/parameter.
I was expecting the sheets swap as I click the options on filter/parameter.

There have been many articles written about this topic, for example this is a great in depth article on sheet swapping.
Sheet swapping works basically as a filter, when a parameter is selected it activates a value and you use this value as a filter on your worksheets. You don't need to use the show/hide buttons in this case. Make sure your calculated swapping field is in your filter pane of both sheets and is set to match its respective parameter value.

Use Dynamic Visibility Zones for swapping sheets. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dks5UAq3OI

I did that (making sure the calculated swapping field is also in my filter pane of both sheets and is set to match its respective parameter value), but still doesn't work. I don't know what went wrong.
